# Prevent react app from making actual request when testing

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I use jest and react-testing-library to test React app. When test React application, sometimes we might forget to mock our API call, your app will make actual requests to the server.

How to throw an error when we forget to mock an API test? I have seen Kent C.Dodds write a code for that in setupTest.js but I cannot find it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's here https://github.com/kentcdodds/bookshelf/blob/4057cf5d5d6c0c3d40868abb804ffe3acf850c97/src/setupTests.js#L3-L13

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(window, 'fetch').mockImplementation((...args) => {
    console.warn('window.fetch is not mocked for this call', ...args)
    return Promise.reject(new Error('This must be mocked!'))
  })
})

afterEach(() => {
  window.fetch.mockRestore()
})
```

Comment: You are the best, I think ppl will find this script useful